# expected primary expression in algorithm::binary_search call

Tags: c++, list, compiler-errors, binary-search

I hope this is not painfully obvious. I am getting this cryptic error :

```
fold.cpp:92: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
```

The line that it is referring to is:

```
if (binary_search (corpus.begin(),corpus.end(), left, customArray::operator<(customArray)))
```

I arrived at this error after using the simpler call:

```
if (binary_search (corpus.begin(),corpus.end(), left))
```

and getting this error message (the important part is the note at the end, saying to change it to the above call)

```
In function ‘bool std::binary_search(_ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator, const _Tp&)     [with _ForwardIterator = std::_List_iterator<customArray>, _Tp = std::string [3]]’:
fold.cpp:92:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_algo.h:4240: error: no match for ‘operator<’ in ‘__val <    __i. std::_List_iterator<_Tp>::operator* [with _Tp = customArray]()’
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_algo.h: In function ‘_ForwardIterator   std::lower_bound(_ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator, const _Tp&) [with _ForwardIterator =   std::_List_iterator<customArray>, _Tp = std::string [3]]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_algo.h:4239:   instantiated from ‘bool    std::binary_search(_ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator, const _Tp&) [with _ForwardIterator =   std::_List_iterator<customArray>, _Tp = std::string [3]]’
fold.cpp:92:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_algo.h:2906: error: no match for ‘operator<’ in   ‘__middle. std::_List_iterator<_Tp>::operator* [with _Tp = customArray]() < __val’
fold.cpp:16: note: candidates are: bool customArray::operator<(customArray)
```

Essentially, I am trying to use a binary search on a linked list of custom (array type) objects. The rest of the relavent code is here:

```
// here is the custom class I am using in the list
class customArray
{
public:

  // this is a somewhat lame way to compare, but it seems to work
  bool operator< (customArray temp)
  {
    return array[0] < temp.array[0];
  }

 bool operator> (customArray temp)
  {
    return array[0] > temp.array[0];
  }

  bool operator== (customArray temp)
  {
    return ((array[0] == temp.array[0]) && (array[1] == temp.array[1]) && (array[2] == temp.array[2]));
  }

  string array[3];
};

//All of this stuff is in main

customArray one;
//some processing here to fill one
corpus.push_back (one);

// sort the list 
corpus.sort();
corpus.unique();

string left [3];

if (binary_search (corpus.begin(),corpus.end(), left, customArray::operator<(customArray)))
{

}
```

I hope this is easy to understand. Let me know if there is any way that I can clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first error message was because `binary_search` uses `<` on the iterators, but list's iterators don't support `<`. This error has nothing to do with whether or not you pass a comparison function as an argument to `binary_search`.

Your second error message is because you specified the type when passing the function as an argument. That's basically the same as calling a function as `f(int x)` instead of `f(x)`, which is syntactically incorrect. It should just be `customArray::operator<`. However, as I said before, that won't help you because you'll just get the first error message again.

Basically you can't perform a binary search on a linked list.

Comment: Oh, this is a bigger problem than I realized. I guess I'll have to switch over to using a vector. Thank you very much! I'll accept this answer just as soon as it let me.

Answer (score 0):

You are putting the whole signature of your functor inside your call to binary_search. You don't need the 'bool' there.

Comment: Thanks! However, if the 'bool' is removed, it still gives the    error:fold.cpp:92: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token

Comment: @MichaelRauh Since your CustomArray has an operator< then I don't think you should have to explicitly pass it.

Comment: That makes sense, I'll have to bear that in mind when using the vector version.

Comment: @MichaelRauh Also, you are searching for a string in a vector of customArray. That's a problem too.

Comment: I am intending to search for a string. The overloaded == allows for this (I hope).

Comment: @MichaelRauh I don't think so. Read this carefully. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/binary_search/
the third argument of binary_search has the template type T which is the same as that on which the iterators are created.

Comment: I'll have to look into this. Thanks for the heads up!